# « Moi qui fait » ou « moi qui fais » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

Devant choisir parmi les deux en rédigeant mon précédent commentaire, j'ai demandé rapidement à google son point de vue : 140M pour « moi qui fait », contre seulement 5M pour « moi qui fais ».

Puis, réfléchissant un peu, je me suis dit que « nous qui faisons, vous qui faites, … » et qu'il n'y a donc pas de raison à ce « moi qui fait ».

Est-ce l'un de ces cas où les deux sont acceptés ? Sinon, qu'est-ce qui peut expliquer cette tendance générale à utiliser « moi qui fait » ? Pourquoi me suis-je moi-même posé la question ?

Comment: Tentant de répondre à la toute dernière question, je me rends compte que j'ai pu concevoir le pronom « moi » comme une sorte de projection à la troisième personne. Un peu comme si j'avais utilisé mon prénom à la place.

Comment: tu écris tes mémoires peut-être? http://www.unige.ch/lettres/framo/enseignements/methodes/figurationsoi/fsintegr.html#fs011300

Comment: @Joubarc: Nullement. (Ça ne tiendrait peut-être pas dans un commentaire sur FL&U ;-)) Mais j'imagine que le général écrivait de toutes façons « il » et « lui » pour parler de lui-même, c'est donc un cas différent. J'en reste pour ma part à des considérations purement grammaticales ;-)

Comment: Attention, l'estimation du nombre d'occurrences d'une recherche Google n'est pas du tout fiable, ça lui arrive de répondre plus pour `"titi toto tutu"` que pour `"toto tutu"`. On peut faire un meilleur test avec [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=moi+qui+fais%2Cmoi+qui+fait&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3). `moi qui fais` domine nettement `moi qui fait` sans l'écraser.

Comment: A souligner : Bien que la phrase *moi qui est* soit attestée, elle sera perçue comme étant nettement moins standard que *moi qui suis*.

Comment: Oui mais la mesure est pertubée avec google, car le premier résultat est... cette question :-) De toutes façons avec Google, la situation est pire que pire, puisque si j'écris "moi qui fai", il me propose en premier pour compléter "moi qui fait", et jamais "moi qui fais"... mais bon, c'est vrai, il propose "moi qui fait l'amour", c'est pas une mauvaise idée (mince c'est grammaticalement fautif)

Comment: En passant la phrase au futur, on se rend compte qu'il y a une version qui sonne mieux. "C'est moi qui fera..." est assez atroce.

Comment: Un autre exemple : > "C'est toi qui es responsable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'abord évidemment il y a la **régle générale** de l'accord du verbe en nombre et avec la personne se rattachant à l'antécédent.

Même là, **parfois l'accord se fera selon le sens** voulu : « *J'aime mieux que ce soit vous que moi qui* VOUS LANCIEZ *dans les orages et les tempêtes de la Chambre* (BALZAC, *Député d'Arcis*, Pl., p. 653) ». Sauf que le « **pronom personnel nominalisé** est de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne : *C'était toujours* [...] *le pauvre moi qui* RÉPONDAIT *de tout* (DE GAULLE, *Mém. de guerre*, 1.1, p. 280) » (LBU14§931R1).

Ensuite, l'**histoire** :

> On a pu autrefois mettre le verbe à la 3<sup>e</sup> personne alors que
> l'antécédent de *qui* est un pronom de la 1<sup>e</sup> ou de la
> 2<sup>e</sup> : *C'est moy qui lui* DIRA (SCARRON, *Héritier
> ridicule*, I, 1 ). — *Ce ne seroit pas moy qui* SE FEROIT *prier*
> (Mol., *Sgan.*, II). [...] Dans *qui est* signifiant « c'est-à-dire », le verbe ne
> s'accordait pas avec l'antécédent, peut-être parce que l'on considérait *qui* comme neutre [...] — *Me de St Pars luy avoit envoyé* [...] *trois personnes à héberger, qui* EST *un organiste, sa femme et une autre* (MAINTENON, *Lettres*, t. III, p. 284)(LBU14§931H1).

Puis pour **reproduire le parler populaire** qui met « assez souvent » la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du verbe pour un antécédent de 1<sup>e</sup> ou 2<sup>e</sup> : *C'est moi qui le* PAIERA (R. BENJAMIN, *Gaspard*, VI).

Ou dans **un tour** avec « *ne ... que* + pronom personnel + *qui*, on trouve parfois l'accord avec un mot comme *personne* sous-entendu [...] *Il n'y a que moi qui* EST *parfait* (PÉGUY,
*Myst. des saints Innoc.*, p. 9 ». On notera que :

> Cet accord n'était pas rare chez **les classiques** :*<sup>+</sup>Il n'y aura que vous qui* SOIT *noble* (MALHERBE, t. Il, p. 420). — *Je n'ay trouvé que vous qui* FUST *digne de moy* (CORN., *Psyché*, IV, 3). — *£t ne verrons que nous qui* SÇACHE *bien écrire* (MOL., *F.
> sav.*, III, 2). — *Il ne voit dans son sort que moy qui* S'INTÉRESSE
> (RAC., *Brit.*, Il, 3) [...] (LBU14§931H2).

Par ailleurs, « quand l'antécédent est un **mot mis en apostrophe** [...],
le verbe est à la 2<sup>e</sup> personne (du singulier ou du pluriel, selon
que l'on tutoie ou vouvoie l'interlocuteur ; du pluriel quand on
s'adresse à plusieurs) : *Ah ! insensé, qui* CROIS *que je ne suis pas toi !* (HUGO, *Contempl*, Préf.)[...] ». (LBU14§931b)

Mais encore, « lorsque *qui* a pour **antécédent un attribut** dont le verbe est à
la l<sup>re</sup> ou à la 2<sup>e</sup> personne, l'usage hésite entre l'accord avec l'attribut (3<sup>e</sup> pers.) et l'accord avec le pronom de la l<sup>re</sup> ou de la 2<sup>e</sup> personne. [...] Si le verbe principal est négatif ou interrogatif, l'accord se fait avec
l'attribut : *Vous n'êtes pas un homme qui* AIME *la flatterie*. *Êtes-vous un homme qui* SAIT
*réfléchir* ? *Êtes-vous Dupont qui* m'A *écrit hier* ? — *Êtes-vous celui qui* A *commis le
crime ?* (HUGO, *Lucr. Borgia*, II, I, 3.) [...] Quand le verbe principal n'est ni négatif ni interrogatif, l'accord se fait le plus souvent avec l'attribut, si celui-ci est un pronom démonstratif ou un nom précédé de l'article défini (sauf avec un numéral cardinal) ou du démonstratif : *Je suis celui qui* TIENT *le globe* [dit l'empereur] (HUGO, *Lég.*, XIX, 2) (LBU14§931c)

Sans compter que « si ce qui précède le relatif est un **syntagme complexe**, on doit
déterminer où se trouve effectivement l'antécédent » (LBU14§931d) (quoique certaines formules permettent un choix : « *J'en crois un homme comme vous qui* A *vu par ses yeux*, ou : *qui* AVEZ *vu par vos yeux* (LlTTRÉ, s. v. *qui*, 5°).

Tout en se rappellant évidemment que « quand ***chacun*** s'intercale après le pronom relatif *qui* avec un pluriel comme antécédent, c'est ce pluriel qui doit déterminer l'accord : *J'ai deux sœurs qui chacune* ONT *leur voiture*.(LBU14§931e)<sup>1</sup>

Il est parfaitement naturel que l'on se pose des questions sur le sujet.

---

- Selon le moment dans l'histoire, ce pouvait être accepté ou non.
- Malgré la régle générale de l'accord du verbe en nombre et avec la personne se rattachant à l'antécédent, la langue populaire emploie « assez souvent » le verbe à la troisième pour l'antécédent de première ou deuxième personne, et certains la reproduisent à dessein ou non.
- La personne qui pose la question a peut-être lu ses classiques ou a observé certaines nuances, avec raison.

---

<sub><sup>1.</sup> L'ensemble du contenu est extrait du propos riche, passionnant et incontournable se trouvant dans *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, à § 931. Dix ans après la question et quarante après M. Grevisse, dont on se souviendra toujours, son propos nous rappelle, entre autres, qu'on a déjà fait mieux.</sub>

Answer (score 26):

« Moi qui fait » est simplement faux. Le pronom *qui* se réfère à la première personne, et on fait l'accord en conséquence. Alors : « Moi qui fais ».

> Qu'est-ce qui peut expliquer cette tendance ?

Le problème est que *qui* se réfère dans la majorité des cas à une troisième personne, et *qui fait* (sans *moi*) est correct. En plus, il n'y a pas de différence de prononciation, et les algorithmes d'orthographie n'indiquent pas d'erreur.

Comment: C'est vrai que les propositions subordonnées sont souvent à la troisième personne. L'habitude de lire « qui fait » pourrait donc expliquer cette tendance générale à faire l'erreur.

Comment: @Stéphane: "qui fait" apparait aussi, correctement, dans les questions.

Answer (score 10):

En considérant le pluriel, au présent « je fais » devient « nous faisons » et :

- « Moi qui fais du bruit, … » devient « Nous qui faisons du bruit, … »

Dans le cas d'un passé composé, « j'ai fait » devient « nous avons fait » et :

- « C'est moi qui l'ai fait » devient « c'est nous qui l'avons fait ».

Je pense que l'abondance de résultats de Google tendant pour l'autre sens dérive de cette seconde expression au passé composé dont le participe passé est *fait*.

Comment: Pour la recherche google, il faut utiliser des quotes: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22moi+qui+fait%22 et http://www.google.com/search?q=%22moi+qui+fais%22 ; le deuxième cas (au passé) ne devrait pas fausser les résultats.

Comment: Le désormais célèbre ngram (http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=moi+qui+fait%2Cmoi+qui+fais&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) montre quand même un net avantage à la forme correcte même si l'on voit une progression alarmante de la faute ces dernières années.

Answer (score 5):

« Moi qui fais », bien sûr. 
Pour les francophones, une astuce : pensez à passer au pluriel. « Nous qui est » ne vous semble-t-il pas atroce, comparé à « Nous qui sommes » ?

Comment: La remarque est juste, mais il me semble que l'erreur correspondante au pluriel serait plutôt *Nous qui sont*, ce qui est, nous sommes bien d'accord, à peu près aussi atroce.

Comment: Une autre astuce : changer de verbe. « C'est moi qui *vais* », ou « c'est moi qui *va* » ?

Comment: @Qeole, encore faut-il tomber sur le bon verbe... Il n'y a que être, avoir et aller qui font cette différence...

Answer (score 4):

A priori l'accord correct serait "moi qui fais", le moi étant la forme pronominale du "je". ([source](http://sosgrammaire.voila.net/rglmoiqui.html))

Answer (score 3):

On peut raisonner comme une abréviation de la phrase originale :

> Qui (est **la personne qui**) fai**t** ?
>
> C'est **moi**, la *personne qui fait* !

Ce qui donne :

> C'est moi, (la personne) qui fait !
>
> C'est moi, —————— qui fait !

Comment: Et donc "nous qui font" et "vous qui font" ?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez : Ce n'est pas faux ça ? C'est moi qui fai**s**, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris Non, ce n'est pas faux. C'est une bonne réponse à la question posée: *Sinon (c'est à dire: si c'est incorrect), qu'est-ce qui peut expliquer cette tendance générale à utiliser « moi qui fait » ? Pourquoi me suis-je moi-même posé la question ?*

Answer (score 0):

Une règle : rechercher quel mot reprend « qui » et accorder le verbe avec lui.

- **C'est moi qui va à la piscine* est faux, *qui* désigne la 1<sup>e</sup> personne, donc *C'est moi qui vais à la piscine* ;
- **C'est toi qui va à la piscine* est faux, *qui* désigne la 2<sup>e</sup> personne, donc *C'est toi qui vas à la piscine* ;
- *C'est lui qui va à la piscine* est correct, *qui* désigne la 3<sup>e</sup> personne.

Autres exemples :

- **C'est moi qui fait*, faux ⇒ *C'est moi qui fais* ;
- *C'est lui qui fait*, juste ;
- **C'est toi qui veut jouer au ballon*, faux ⇒ *C'est toi qui veux jouer au ballon*.

Answer (score 0):

C'est *moi* qui **fais** : la conjugaison du verbe se fait par rapport au sujet « **je** ».

Answer (score 0):

Je viens de lire le fil de conversation et je ne comprends même pas pourquoi ce *« C'est moi qui fais »* est si difficile à conjuguer. La phrase dit elle-même que « c'est **moi** qui fais » donc c'est **je**, pas *il ou elle*. On conjugue alors **je fais**.

> C'est moi qui fais.