# Tu es le seul qui me parle(s) en Français ?

Tags: pronoms, accord

Dans la phrase suivante : "Tu es le seul qui me parle en Français" est-ce que le verbe *parler* s'accorde à la deuxième ou troisième personne ?

Quelle est la règle générale ?

Comment: [This](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/549/moi-qui-fait-ou-moi-qui-fais) might actually be a more exact duplicate, actually.

Answer (score 4):

Le verbe s'accorde avec le sujet, mais le sujet ne peut se trouver que dans la proposition où le verbe est lui-même. Dans ce cas le pronom sujet « qui » est ce sujet. Le verbe  s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le pronom relatif.

- Les camions qui étaient au bord de la route **sont** reparti**s**.
- La maison qui s'est écroulée **était** construit**e** en briques.
- C'est nous qui **sommes** forcé**s** de partir.

L'antécédent de « qui » est « le seul » ; comme la personne est la troisième personne du singulier la forme du verbe est « parle ».

[français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-71001.php)

Comment: Le troisième exemple n'est pas une relative. C'est une mise en relief/clivée...

Comment: @GAMPUB Comment réconcilier ce point de vue avec le fait que "qui" est quand même considéré comme un pronom relatif, ce qui plus est, un pronom relatif sujet, et le besoin, étant donné la présence de deux verbes, de deux sujets ? On ne peut pas dire qu'il n'y a pas un cas de proposition relative ; il est bien question d'une telle proposition mais elle est utilisée dans le contexte particulier de construction de mise en relief  au moyen d'une phrase clivée. (voir par exemple http://uoh.univ-montp3.fr/j_ameliore_ma_maitrise_du_francais/T-COM-titres-resumes/co/module_titres_resumes_8.html)

Comment: Tout simplement en constatant que la forme *qui* remplace la conjonction de subordination *que* quand la phrase enchâssée n'a pas de sujet, particulièrement dans ce qu'on appelle les dépendances à longue distance : *C'est nous que vous savez qui sommes venus.* et pas *C'est nous qui vous savez que/qui sommes venus* Parmi les nombreuses références, il y a [Bérard 2012](https://hal.univ-lorraine.fr/tel-01749301). PS. Le lien vers l'UOH ne marche pas pour moi...

Comment: @GAMPUB Je vois, une théorie très récente (2018); elle a encore à faire ses preuves. « C'est nous que vous savez qui sommes venus.» m'apparait comme non grammatical; il me semble que « c'est nous » ne peut pas donner suite à la  conjonction « que » ; si « que  » est le pronom relatif, de même la sémantique ne tient pas : on peut très  bien savoir quelque chose mais certainement jamais quelqu'un.

Comment: Une référence récente. Une construction identifiée depuis très longtemps : *C'est Paul que Yves croit que Jean sait que Nicolas pense qui est venu...*

Comment: @GAMPUB C'est phrase est un véritable charabia et loin d'être une relique grammaticale, sauf en tant qu'exemple notoire de la sorte la plus horrible. « Nicolas pense qui est venu » ne peut être que  « Nicolas pense **savoir** qui est venu » (tout d'abord), autrement c'est du non sens (on ne pense pas quelqu'un).