# Not sure why I got these grammar questions incorrect

Tags: grammaire

I've been learning French for a few months and wanted to test how my grammar was doing so searched google for grammar tests and in the top few results was this site:http://www.frenchlanguageguide.com/languagetools/frenchadvancedtest1.asp I felt I did quite well but when the answers came I found I got many wrong but don't know why.

Can someone explain why these are incorrect?

```
Question 3: Nous irons libres à midi.
Your answer: serons
```

I really thought `serons` was correct here?

```
Question 4: Il regarderai le match de foot avec toi.
Your answer: Je
```

I'm sure that `Je` goes with `regarderai`. I even checked with online translators and the given correct sentence was flagged as incorrect.

```
Question 5: Marie voudrait étudier architecte.
Your answer: devenir
```

I thought `devinir` was correct or at least an acceptable alternative?

```
Question 6: Le grand fan de Jacques Brel, mon père possède tous ses disques.
Your answer: Étant
```

I thought `Étant` made more sense here than `Le`.

```
Question 8: Quand Marc est rentré, Marie est déjà arrivée.
Your answer: était
```

I thought this was like 'when Marc arrived, Marie *was* already there.

```
Question 17: C'est moi qui suis en retard.
Your answer: étais
```

Surely `étais` is also acceptable here?

Unless I'm mistaken it seems my answers would at least be acceptable alternatives even if not what they were looking for so not sure why they were marked as simple incorrect. Anyway, if someone can give me some insight on these that would be great.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  Some of your answers absolutely work (and online tests aren't always coded well), but there are too many unrelated concepts here.  Voting to close.

Comment: Native speaker here. I confirm that in all cases except question 17, your answer is valid and the official answer is unambiguously wrong. For 17, both *suis* and *étais* are valid (with a different meaning: ”I'm the one who is/was late“.), but the site only offers *était* as a choice, and that is not valid.

Comment: Also Q1: the correct answer is “**vont** se lever”, not *sont*. Q2: “on mange le **mieux**”, not *meilleur*. Q7: “Paul **la lui** offre”, not *lui la*. The official answers for Q1-8 are wrong and the official answers for Q9-Q20 are correct.

Comment: It looks like it's a terrible resource, there's mistakes all over the site. The first 8 questions are plain wrong.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat Well yeah those are exactly the questions that I posted. I'm surprised a site like that, even ranking high in google could have so many obvious mistakes. That's why I posted here to be sure since I'm not a master of French and thus I assumed it was more likely I was wrong than the site...despite the fact that went so much against my natural instinct here.

Comment: Dialang is a good reliable free tool that you might want to try. See what I say about it in [this answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/240/17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 3: Nous irons libres à midi. Your answer: serons.

You are right; the correct answer is 'serons'. There is a mistake here.

> Question 4: Il regarderai le match de foot avec toi. Your answer: Je

Either 'je regarderai' or 'il regardera' but not 'il regarderai'. You are right as well.

> Question 5: Marie voudrait étudier architecte. Your answer: devenir

In English, one would say 'Marie would like to study architecture.' This is conveyed in French with the present conditional of vouloir (or aimer) which is voudrait (for the third person). Vouloir is immediately followed by another verb in the infinitive (when there is no change of the subject in the sentence; cf. Marie voudrait que tu fasses la cuisine. Note the usage of subjunctive here.)

The problematic part is “*étudier architecte” which is a meaningless jumble of words. “Étudier l'architecture” would be correct but “devenir architecte” is more idiomatic for a child or teenager stating their career preferences; “voudrait étudier l'architecture” would be the right formulation to describe a student's preferences when she's applying to colleges. –
(@merci Gilles 'SO nous est hostile)

> Question 6: Le grand fan de Jacques Brel, mon père possède tous ses disques. Your answer: Étant

I agree with you that Étant makes more sense here.

> Question 8: Quand Marc est rentré, Marie est déjà arrivée. Your
> answer: était

Again you are right. Quand Marc est rentré, Marie était déjà arrivée. When Marc came home, Marie had already arrived.

> Question 17: C'est moi qui suis en retard. Your answer: était

Here the correction is indeed the right one. The imperfect of être would fit as well if, instead of était, it was étais. That is, C'est **moi qui étais** en retard.

To quote user @livresque "Please ask one question per question. Some of your answers absolutely work (and online tests aren't always coded well), but there are too many unrelated concepts here."

Comment: Yes the last one should be `étais` that was just a typo that I've fixed now. So I was actually correct about every single question? The site has some major errors...that surprised me since it's one of the top results in google.

Comment: @Hasen. I am not teaching French, but I think your level of French is already quite well. I guess you should try another site. Keep in touch with FSE because it is the right place to improve your French. In the following question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar several useful webpages are being put together.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just really wanted to confirm that those were indeed incorrect as I thought since it's somewhat unexpected on sites like that. I of course assumed I would be wrong as a French learner rather than the test site being wrong. I learn grammar in a natural way so I don't learn actual grammar rules. Thus I just felt I was correct when doing that test. Btw in English we say '...your level of French is already quite _good_'. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Hasen You are welcome:-)!

Comment: Par exemple il y a des réponses [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/549/moi-qui-fait-ou-moi-qui-fais) for *moi qui suis* questions.

Comment: Your explanation for Q5 is incomplete. “vouloir + infinitif” isn't the problematic part. The problematic part is “\*étudier architecte” which is a meaningless jumble of words. “Étudier l'architecture” would be correct but “devenir architecte” is more idiomatic for a child or teenager stating their career preferences; “voudrait étudier l'architecture” would be the right formulation to describe a student's preferences when she's applying to colleges.

Comment: @Gilles 'SO nous est hostile' True and my answer was indeed “devenir architecte”. You're right he didn't quite explain that part in full in his answer. Perhaps he can edit it.